# A formalization of the soft sciences

Tags: reference-request

Branches of physics have been formalized in mathematical language. Have there been texts where the same has been done for chemistry, biology, neuroscience, sociology, and astronomy? I would love to see such texts. It would be very interesting to read.

Comment: I don't think you can formalize causal relationships in mathematics or logic, so I doubt that you can formalize them in any science including physics. The ancient Greek philosophers thought that you could do physics purely by introspection (on paper) -- with quite laughable results -- but we now know that data from physical experiments are indispensable.